# Mysql date_add 1 year

Tags: mysql, perl

Can someone help me figure out why adding 1 year doesn't work for me?

I have 6 other conditions (1 day, 1 week, 2 month, etc). The only one NOT working is the year.

Anyone see why? In case it matters, this is Perl.

```
elsif ($data{length} == "6month")
{
$store = qq(INSERT INTO main (creator_name,email2,relationship,reason,email1,name1,creator_email,email3,name2,name3,creator_url,victim_url,length_of_stay,release_date) VALUES("$data{creatorname}","$data{email2}","$data{relationship}","$data{reason}","$data{email1}","$data{person1}","$data{creatoremail}","$data{email3}","$data{person2}","$data{person3}", "$creatorURL", "$victimURL","$data{length}", DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) );
}
elsif($data{length} == "1year")
{
$store = qq(INSERT INTO main (creator_name,email2,relationship,reason,email1,name1,creator_email,email3,name2,name3,creator_url,victim_url,length_of_stay,release_date) VALUES("$data{creatorname}","$data{email2}","$data{relationship}","$data{reason}","$data{email1}","$data{person1}","$data{creatoremail}","$data{email3}","$data{person2}","$data{person3}", "$creatorURL", "$victimURL","$data{length}", DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) );
}

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($store);
$sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with a better description than *“doesn’t work”* and *“not working”*

Answer (score 3):

You should use 'eq' operator for comparing strings in perl.

```
elsif ( $data{length} eq '6month') {
```

also it will be better if you will use placeholders in your sql statements. because:

- They are almost the same
- It will protect you from sql injections
- You can use one prepared statement several times, it's faster when
  you similar statements in loop
- You will reduce code repeating. Do not repeat yourself

Your code will looks like:

```
my $interval = 0;
...
elsif ( $data{length} eq '6month' ) {
    $interval = 6;
}
elsif( $data{length} eq '1year' ) {
    $interval = 12;
}
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO main ( creator_name, email2, relationship, reason, email1, name1, creator_email, email3, name2, name3, creator_url, victim_url, length_of_stay, release_date ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? MONTH) );' );
$sth->execute( $data{creatorname},
               $data{email2},
               $data{relationship},
               $data{reason},
               $data{email1},
               $data{person1},
               $data{creatoremail},
               $data{email3},
               $data{person2},
               $data{person3},
               $creatorURL,
               $victimURL,
               $data{length},
               $interval
             ) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

If you have to do this insert in loop move `$dbh->prepare` statement outside this loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem at root is that you aren't enabling warnings; if you had, you would have gotten a warning like this:

```
$ perl
use warnings;
$data{length} = "1year";

if ($data{length} == "1month") {
    print "yes, 1month does == 1year\n";
}
__END__
Argument "1month" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at - line 4.
Argument "1year" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at - line 4.
yes, 1month does == 1year
```